# Storing the data representations of multiple, differently typed objects in a single Data instance

Tags: ios, swift, pointers, nsdata, foundation

#### Motivation

To my knowledge, `Data` is a struct that abstracts a byte buffer. It references a physical area in memory, in other words: a contiguous number of bytes. Now I want to efficiently store multiple values in memory (as raw data), where the values are *not all of the same type*.

My definition of efficient here ≔ Store all those values without any unused buffer / gap bytes.

#### Storing the raw data in memory

```
let a: UInt8 = 39
let b: Int32 = -20001
let string: String = "How awesome is this data?!"
```

Now I want to store the data of all those values sequentially in memory, without any type information.

```
let data = [a.asData, b.asData, string.asData].concatenated()
```

Imagine that the `.asData` property retrieves the byte representations of each instance as a `[UInt8]` array and then wraps those in a `Data` instance. The `concetenated()` method then just concatenates these 3 `Data` instances to a single `Data` instance as follows:

```
extension Collection where Element == Data {
    func concatenated() -> Data {
        reduce(into: Data()) { (result, nextDataChunk) in
            result.append(nextDataChunk)
        }
    }
}
```

#### Reading the data back from memory into the respective types

Let's assume this all worked great and I now have this single `Data` instance from which I want to restore the 3 original values (with their original types). This is what I do:

```
var cursor = 0

let a: UInt8 = data.withUnsafeBytes { pointer in
    pointer.load(fromByteOffset: cursor, as: UInt8.self)
}
cursor += MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size // +1

let b: Int32 = data.withUnsafeBytes { pointer in
    pointer.load(fromByteOffset: cursor, as: Int32.self)
}
cursor += MemoryLayout<Int32>.size // +4

let string: String = data.withUnsafeBytes { pointer in
    pointer.load(fromByteOffset: cursor, as: String.self)
}
cursor += MemoryLayout<String>.size // +16
```

#### The Problem

The problem is that this throws a runtime error:

> Fatal error: load from misaligned raw pointer

and I know exactly why:

`Int32` has an alignment of 4 (because it's 4 bytes long). In other words: When reading data with a raw pointer, the first byte of the `Int32` must be at an index that is a multiple of 4. But as the first value is a `UInt8` only, the data bytes for the `Int32` start at index 1, which is *not* a multiple of 4. Thus, I get the error.

---

### My question is this:

- Can I somehow use the raw `Data` that represents instances of different types to recreate such instances without alignment errors? How?
- And if this is not possible, is there a way to automatically align the `Data` chunks correctly when concatenating them in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue about misaligned data is that you need to use Data's subdata method. Besides that you can create some helpers to make your life easier as follow:

This would convert any numeric type to Data:

```
extension Numeric {
    var data: Data {
        var bytes = self
        return .init(bytes: &bytes, count: MemoryLayout<Self>.size)
    }
}
```

This would convert any type that conforms to String Protocol to Data (String/Substring)

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var data: Data { .init(utf8) }
}
```

This would convert any valid utf8 encoded sequence of bytes (UInt8) to string

```
extension DataProtocol {
    var string: String? { String(bytes: self, encoding: .utf8) }
}
```

This is a generic method to convert the bytes to object or to a collection (array) of objects:

```
extension ContiguousBytes {
    func object<T>() -> T { withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: T.self) } }
    func objects<T>() -> [T] { withUnsafeBytes { .init($0.bindMemory(to: T.self)) } }
}
```

and a simplified generic version to concatenate an array of data:

```
extension Collection where Element == DataProtocol {
    var data: Data { .init(joined()) }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let a: UInt8 = 39
let b: Int32 = -20001
let string: String = "How awesome is this data?!"
let data = [a.data, b.data, string.data].data

// just set the cursor (index) at the start position
var cursor = data.startIndex
// get the subdata from that position onwards
let loadedA: UInt8 = data.subdata(in: cursor..<data.endIndex).object()  // 39
// advance your cursor for the next position
cursor = cursor.advanced(by: MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size)
// get your next object
let loadedB: Int32 = data.subdata(in: cursor..<data.endIndex).object()  // -20001
// advance your position to the start of the string data
cursor = cursor.advanced(by: MemoryLayout<Int32>.size)
// load the subdata as string
let loadedString = data.subdata(in: cursor..<data.endIndex).string  // "How awesome is this data?!"
```

---

edit/update:
Of course loading the string only works because it is located at the end of your collection of bytes otherwise you would need to use 8 bytes to store its size:

```
let a: UInt8 = 39
let b: Int32 = -20001
let string: String = "How awesome is this data?!"
let c: Int = .max
let data = [a.data, b.data, string.count.data, string.data, c.data].data

var cursor = data.startIndex
let loadedA: UInt8 = data.subdata(in: cursor..<data.endIndex).object()  // 39
print(loadedA)
cursor = cursor.advanced(by: MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size)
let loadedB: Int32 = data.subdata(in: cursor..<data.endIndex).object()  // -20001
print(loadedB)
cursor = cursor.advanced(by: MemoryLayout<Int32>.size)
let stringCount: Int = data.subdata(in: cursor..<data.endIndex).object()
print(stringCount)
cursor = cursor.advanced(by: MemoryLayout<Int>.size)
let stringEnd = cursor.advanced(by: stringCount)

if let loadedString = data.subdata(in: cursor..<stringEnd).string {  // "How awesome is this data?!"
    print(loadedString)
    cursor = stringEnd
    let loadedC: Int = data.subdata(in: cursor..<data.endIndex).object()  // 9223372036854775807
    print(loadedC)
}
```

This would print

> 39
> -20001
> 26
> How awesome is this data?!
> 9223372036854775807

Comment: You are correct, the key is creating new `Data` instances for each data chunk to escape the alignment problem. I was hoping to find a way to access the raw bytes of any primitive type with the same generic method, but it seems like I cannot do that? (i.e. I need different `data` implementations for `String`s and `Numeric`s.) Is there any way to know a `String`'s size without storing it as well? And do you happen to know why `MemorySize<String>` always returns a fixed value of 16 bytes when a string's size is actually flexible?

Comment: There is many different ways to encode a `String`, `.utf8` is one of them but It is the only one that would never fail. All other encoding options would return an optional. Regarding the size `String` is a collection therefore there is no way to predict its size. AFAIK Only those types that have a fixed size can be loaded without the need to set the end index.

Comment: There is also the endianness when encoding and decoding numeric types. If you need to encode/decode a `Date` you can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47502712/2303865)

Comment: btw you might be interested in this related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63022536/2303865)