# How to embed a large array of structs into a program in Swift

Tags: swift, serialization, resources

I have a quite large (~200k) list of simple objects like:

```
struct City {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let lat: Double
    let lon: Double
}
```

and I want to embed in into my application. I believe, hardcoding it in a .swift file is not the best option. I've tried to embed it as a JSON file, but the loading speed is poor for this method. I've also tried a Message Pack serializer, but it seems to be as slow as JSON in my case.

What would be a proper way to embed it? I think, using Core Data would be too much for this situation. I think, with the fact that my data is so simple and I don't need any kind of backward compatibility it must be and easier solution.

Comment: What’s your usage like? Do you really need to load all 200k entries?

Comment: You can embed it as raw data

Comment: Do you need this all this data available in memory all at once?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/63022536/2303865

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64669393/2303865 this might be a better duplicate considering that this struct contains a string