# What is the modern canonical way to support converting ContiguousBytes into both Array and "not-Array"?

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

For example, without this second overload, loading an Array will yield "**UnsafeRawBufferPointer.load out of bounds**". Is there a way to handle both cases without overloads?

```swift
let bytes: [UInt8] = [1, 0, 1, 0]
bytes.load() as Int32 // 0x1_00_01
bytes.load() as [Int16] // [1, 1]
```

```swift
public extension ContiguousBytes {
  func load<T>(_: T.Type = T.self) -> T {
    withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: T.self) }
  }

  func load<Element>(_: [Element].Type = [Element].self) -> [Element] {
    withUnsafeBytes { .init($0.bindMemory(to: Element.self)) }
  }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK you can't.

Comment: I think it would be better to make your generic methods more restricted as it would result in undefined behavior for other kind of types. I have already implemented [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63022536/2303865) to those methods but the point is to avoid its misuse

Comment: Never mind I forgot you like to create generic types using the same name instead of a single character. Btw Why not simply `func load<Element>() -> [Element] {`?

Comment: The arguments allow you to pass a metatype in, the way they do it for e.g. Codable. I don't tend to use metatypes that way, but it won't an API unless we ever get generic properties.

Comment: Yes I know that it allows you to pass the type. I just don't see any advantage over explicitly setting the resulting type or casting when calling that method as you did.

Comment: I don't either, but there's clearly a different opinion going around—otherwise we wouldn't have the terrible requirement of using metatypes with Codable. So I always write these functions like this. I may be making a stupid choice. 

Comment: Itai Ferber is the one to ask about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of having two overloads: you unfortunately can't avoid them. `ContiguousBytes.withUnsafeBytes` gives you access to the underlying *storage* of a type which implements `ContiguousBytes`, so the buffer given by, say, `[UInt8].withUnsafeBytes` will be the actual buffer the array instance is using to *store* data, not a pointer to *itself* in memory (e.g. its length, capacity, storage pointer, etc.).

The reason your first overload can't work is that you'd be calling the equivalent of:

```swift
withUnsafeBytes { rawBuffer in
    rawBuffer.load(as: [Int16].self)
}
```

where `load(as:)` is attempting to read `[1, 0, 1, 0]` as if those contents were the length, capacity, and buffer pointer of a single `[Int16]` instance, but that's not the case — it's only the *contents* of `bytes`.

You need the second overload in order to create a new array with the *contents* of that `UnsafeRawBufferPointer`.

---

As for the actual implementation of your array variant, as of [SE-0333 Expand usability of withMemoryRebound](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0333-with-memory-rebound.md) coming in Swift 5.7, the correct way to do this would be to use `withMemoryRebound(to:_:)`, as the unconditional `bindMemory(to:)` is unsafe if the buffer was already bound to a different type. `withMemoryRebound(to:_:)` is now always safe, even if the buffer is bound, so long as you meet alignment requirements:

> /// A raw buffer may represent memory that has been bound to a type.
> ///   If that is the case, then `T` must be layout compatible with the
> ///   type to which the memory has been bound. This requirement does not
> ///   apply if the raw buffer represents memory that has not been bound
> ///   to any type.

This would look like

```swift
func load<Element>(_: [Element].Type = [Element].self) -> [Element] {
    withUnsafeBytes { rawBuffer in
        rawBuffer.withMemoryRebound(to: Element.self) { typedBuffer in
            Array(typedBuffer)
        }
    }
}
```

[`UnsafeRawBufferPointer.withMemoryRebound(to:_:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/b17b1a9d04db35defeabdf75606586169ab5a08f/stdlib/public/core/UnsafeRawBufferPointer.swift.gyb#L787) will do the math on binding the raw bytes to the right stride of `Element`, though keep in mind that this is *only* valid to do if the alignment of the raw buffer matches the alignment requirements of `Element` — otherwise you'll either crash or trigger undefined behavior.

Comment: So is it available in Xcode 13.3?

Comment: @LeoDabus Should be, yes.

Comment: It's not, though.  I'll keep an eye out for it, and mark this as the answer if it ends up working. In the meantime, your answer is inaccurate without the square brackets from my signature—this overload only applies to array metatypes. I also assume you can use `Array.init` directly instead of making a new closure…?

Comment: Indeed, I was wrong — I believe the proposal was originally slated for Swift 5.6, but will only be coming to Xcode in Swift 5.7. I tried an online Swift playground with Swift 5.6 and it did have `withMemoryRebound` (so I wasn't totally making this up! ) but looks like it didn't make the cut into Xcode 13.3 itself.

Comment: @ItaiFerber yes Xcode 13.3 is Swift 5.6 so we will need to wait the next release

Comment: @Jessy Sorry about that typo, updated the answer to explicitly apply the Array metatype

Comment: Tried your code in Swift 5.7 using the trunk development toolchain. 